# Angular6 HttpClient Cannot Get Json

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

According to the HttpClient in the Angular document.

> The HttpClient.get() method parsed the JSON server response into the anonymous Object type. It doesn't know what the shape of that object is.

My problem is I cannot get the Json directly. I still need to Json.parse in dash-board.component.ts

dash-board.component.ts

```
import { PhoneBasicInfo } from './../Models/PhoneBasicInfo';
import { DashBoardServiceService } from './../Services/dash-board-serv 
ice.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PhoneRecord } from '../Models/PhoneRecords';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dash-board',
  templateUrl: './dash-board.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dash-board.component.css']
})
export class DashBoardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: DashBoardServiceService) { }
  temp:any;
  basicInfo: PhoneBasicInfo;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getPhoneBasicInfo()
          .subscribe(
            basic => {
            console.log(basic['companyName'])    <- I should get the Json Object.
            console.log(JSON.parse(basic));      <- I should not do this.
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry my reputation is not enough to embed a picture

[The console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZxKp.png)

I use JSON.parse to get the data. However, it seems not correct.

So my question is what is the correct way to get the Json via the HttpClient?

Thank you so much.

dash-board-service.service.ts

```
import { PhoneBasicInfo } from './../Models/PhoneBasicInfo';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CATCH_ERROR_VAR } from 
'@angular/compiler/src/output/abstract_emitter';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashBoardServiceService {
  private url = 'http://localhost:57302/api/Phone';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getPhoneBasicInfo(): Observable<PhoneBasicInfo>{
  return this.http.get<PhoneBasicInfo>(this.url);
 }
}
```

PhoneBasicInfo.ts

```
export class PhoneBasicInfo{
    companyName:string;
    firstTrade: string;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. What exactly is the server returning? Seems it returns a string containing the JSON object. (Btw. `PhoneBasicInfo` should be an interface rather than a class)

Comment: Hi Henry,
I use the Postman to get the string from the server.
"{\"companyName\":\"Lucky Company\",\"firstTrade\":\"5/29/2018\"}"

Comment: Don't format it as a string. Use `{"companyName":"Lucky Company","firstTrade":"5/29/2018"}`

Comment: I think, you're server is returning `plain text`, not `json` format. Eighter fix the server or  `return  this.http.get<PhoneBasicInfo>(this.url).pipe(map(data => JSON.parse(data)))`

Comment: Thank you, Henry and Ritwick Dey.
I fix the problem. 
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys. My problem is from the server API. 
Thank you again.